# Creating a Core Data model object which isn't saved to the persistent store

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an iOS application that uses core data.
I've built my `NSManagedObjectModel`. I have an NEOrder entity there.
I've generated NSManagedObject subclasses.

```
@interface NEOrder : NSManagedObject

@property //....

@end
```

I have a UIViewController's subclass. That needs to have and instance variable of type NEOrder.
But I want it to behave like a common custom object:

```
@interface NEOrder : NSObject

@property //....

@end
```

Of course it can be done by creating another .h and .m file with declaration of NEOrder_ subclassing NSObject there. But this file will be very similar to core data generated NSObjectModels, except @synthesize/@dynamic and init method.
I don't want to do the work twice.
Help me please, how can it be done?

if I'm adding init to the generated NEOrder app gets crashed:

```
-(id)init
{
    if (self=[super init])
    {
        self.name=[[NSString alloc] init];
        self.phone=[[NSString alloc] init];
        self.weight=[[NSNumber alloc] init];
        self.fromDirection=[[NEDirection alloc] init];
        self.toDirection=[[NEDirection alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

And another few words about how I want to use it.

```
//NEOrder *order is an instance of view controller
self.order=[NEOrder alloc] init]
//...
self.order.name=@"order name";
self.order.phone=@"12344321";
```

Is it possible? Or I have to create a separate NSObject's subclass for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of your question doesn't make sense:

> I want it to behave like a common custom object.

What do you mean?

The rest of your question suggests you need a single `NEOrder` class, and that you should set up your view controller like this:

**MyViewController.h:**

```
@class NEOrder;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong) NEOrder *order;

@end
```

**MyViewController.m:**

```
#include "NEOrder.h"

@implementation MyViewController

...

@end
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I initialize that object? there's no init method in core data generated model.

Comment: Your view controller also needs a reference to your managed object context. Then, if it needs to initialize a new instance of your object, you can initialize it with `NSEntityDescription`'s `-insertNewObjectForEntityName:inManagedObjectContext`. If you don't want it persisted with your other objects, just use a second managed object context with an in-memory persistent store.

Comment: My view controllers pull NSManagedObjectContext from NEDatabase singleton. So all view controllers operating with the same context and calling `save` method from one of them:`self.managedObjectContext=[[NEDatabase sharedDatabase] managedObjectContext]; /*......*/ [self.managedObjectContext save:nil]` will result in pushing temporarily object into the storage.

Comment: Like I said, if you don't want to persist that instance, create a second managed object context for scratch objects, with an in-memory persistent store, and copy the object into the NEDatabase's context when you're ready.

Comment: I think I'll use this approach. Will inMemoryTypeOfStorage get released when application terminates? Or I have to do it myself in `applicationWillTerminate`?

Answer (score 1):

All classes inherit from NSObject so NSManagedObject inherits from NSObject too. This means that your NEOrder objects will have all the characteristics of an NSObject.

Comment: How must I initialize NEOrder?

Comment: I don't want NEOrder to be initialized using `NSEntityDescription`, I want to initialize it in a common way by calling it's init method. I of course I need all the instances to be initialized in thi init method also.

Comment: This sounds wrong. Why do you not want to create your object using NSEntityDescription's insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:? Could you explain what is the problem if you create your objects in this manner?

Comment: If I push object to NSManagedObjectContext and call `save`to it somewhere temporary object will be pushed to storage

Comment: But you can retrieve the object at any time you want, make changes to it and save again.

Comment: I don't want my object to be saved to storage. And I don't want it to be saved to context. I think I'll use separate storage as @noa suggested or just create new class NEOrder_ inherited from directly NSObject with it's init method etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/chapters/occategories.html). Categories can be used to write methods for a class outside of the actual class. I use them with Core Data models so when I need to regenerate the NSManagedObjectModel for any reason, I keep the methods.